Getting unnecessary log while adding NotificationService Extension in IOS
I am using react native for an app.Just added NotificationService Extension for rich notifications and trying building my project
Getting these unnecessary log in console when hit to run on simulator.
1)tried cleaning the derived data.
2)pod deintegrate and integrate.
3)closing xcode and reopening again.
These types of logs getting
export HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS=/Users/manish.kumar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Medikabazaar-dplnuuermlmktvaimqgotsinmaoj/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/include\ \ /Users/manish.kumar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Medikabazaar-dplnuuermlmktvaimqgotsinmaoj/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ReactCommon-Samples/ReactCommon_Samples.framework/Headers\ /Users/manish.kumar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Medikabazaar-dplnuuermlmktvaimqgotsinmaoj/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ReactCommon/ReactCommon.framework/Headers/react/nativemodule/core\ /Users/manish.kumar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Medikabazaar-dplnuuermlmktvaimqgotsinmaoj/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ReactCommon-Samples/ReactCommon_Samples.framework/Headers/platform/ios\ /Users/manish.kumar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Medikabazaar-dplnuuermlmktvaimqgotsinmaoj/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-NativeModulesApple/React_NativeModulesApple.framework/Headers\ /Users/manish.kumar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Medikabazaar-dplnuuermlmktvaimqgotsinmaoj/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-graphics/React_graphics.framework/Headers/react/renderer/graphics/platform/ios\ "/Users/manish.kumar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Medikabazaar-dplnuuermlmktvaimqgotsinmaoj/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/AppAuth/AppAuth.framework/Headers"\ "/Users/manish.kumar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Medikabazaar-dplnuuermlmktvaimqgotsinmaoj/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/BVLinearGradient/BVLinearGradient.framework/Headers"\ "/Users/manish.kumar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Medikabazaar-dplnuuermlmktvaimqgotsinmaoj/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Base64/Base64.framework/Headers"\ "/Users/manish.kumar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Medikabazaar-dplnuuermlmktvaimqgotsinmaoj/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/CleverTap-iOS-SDK/CleverTapSDK.framework/Headers"\
..................................................................................
...................................
........
